# facing error while uploading file in mvc5 on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-8, devexpress-mvc

I have MVC5 application , where I need to upload file excel and then then create data table of this excel. I use devexpress control to upload file. I use following code to store uploded file and then read in datatable and then store in database.

```
 if (e.UploadedFile.IsValid)
        {
            e.UploadedFile.SaveAs(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + e.UploadedFile.FileName));
            var Filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + e.UploadedFile.FileName));
            DataTable  dtReport = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                dtReport = CreateDataTableFromExcelFile(Filepath, "A1:U", true, "Sheet1").Tables[0];
            }
            catch
            {
            }
              SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy sqlcopy = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(con);
            sqlcopy.DestinationTableName = "table_Name";
            sqlcopy.WriteToServer(dtReport);
            con.Close();
```

If I host this application on IIS on my machine then it works fine. But If I host it on another server then it shows error

> Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MVC_Project_v3\App_Data\UploadTemp\dxupload_19aafa62643d42418b2fe5eaadede3cfcugxrc4e.nrt.tmp' is denied.

Please suggest right solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credential you are using to host the WebSite (the credential you enter in the application pool identity) does not have the privilege to access that directory.

[image]

Add a valid credential here.